# Producing .so libs from .jar

Tags: java, javacv, javacpp

Now I'm trying to complete adding JavaCV to my project and I'm stuck on getting .so libs from javacpp.jar.
Documentation [says](https://github.com/bytedeco/javacpp#instructions-for-android-avian-and-robovm):

> 1. Copy the javacpp.jar file into the libs/ subdirectory, and
> 2. Run this command to produce the *.so library files in libs/armeabi/: 
>     
>      $ java -jar libs/javacpp.jar -classpath bin/   
>      -classpath bin/classes/ \                      
>      -properties<android-arm|android-x86>        
>      -Dplatform.root=/path/to/android-ndk/ \
>      -Dplatform.compiler=/path/to/<arm-linux-androideabi-g++|i686-linux-android-g++>                                           
>      -d libs/<armeabi|x86>/

So my version looks like this

> java -jar libs/javacpp.jar -cp /build/classes/ -properties android-arm
>   -Dplatform.root=D:/AMAZING_THINGS/android-ndk-r13 
>   -Dplatform.compiler=D:/AMAZING_THINGS/android-ndk-r13/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-g++ -d libs/armeabi

I'm trying to extract it in my project folder and get this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: build/classes/main/co
m/mobilestreamer/MobileStreamer$$Lambda$1 (wrong name: com/mobilestreamer/Mobile
Streamer$$Lambda$1)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at org.bytedeco.javacpp.tools.UserClassLoader.findClass(UserClassLoader.
java:72)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
        at org.bytedeco.javacpp.tools.ClassScanner.addClass(ClassScanner.java:61
)
        at org.bytedeco.javacpp.tools.ClassScanner.addMatchingFile(ClassScanner.
java:71)
        at org.bytedeco.javacpp.tools.ClassScanner.addMatchingDir(ClassScanner.j
ava:83)
        at org.bytedeco.javacpp.tools.ClassScanner.addMatchingDir(ClassScanner.j
ava:81)
        at org.bytedeco.javacpp.tools.ClassScanner.addMatchingDir(ClassScanner.j
ava:81)
        at org.bytedeco.javacpp.tools.ClassScanner.addMatchingDir(ClassScanner.j
ava:81)
        at org.bytedeco.javacpp.tools.ClassScanner.addMatchingDir(ClassScanner.j
ava:81)
        at org.bytedeco.javacpp.tools.ClassScanner.addMatchingDir(ClassScanner.j
ava:81)
        at org.bytedeco.javacpp.tools.ClassScanner.addPackage(ClassScanner.java:
95)
        at org.bytedeco.javacpp.tools.Builder.classesOrPackages(Builder.java:607
)
        at org.bytedeco.javacpp.tools.Builder.main(Builder.java:805)
```

As I'm newbie to cmd and other staff related to this field I can't fix this. So what should I do to make it work?
Thx.

Comment: Does it work if you append at the end of the command the classes containing the `native` methods? It seems like it's having problems loading unrelated classes.

Comment: @Samuel Audet There is only one class which uses native methods. After adding it to the end of the command it drops "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: StreamingPagePresen
ter".

Comment: In Java, the class name includes the package name...

Comment: @Samuel Audet Yeah, my fault, but still getting the same error

Comment: Then the class isn't in the path you specified with `-cp`.